# Instrumented code causing infinite recursion loop

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

How can I prevent a suspected infinite loop in the following scenario?

- The entire C++ codebase is instrumented by clang at build time, using an LLVM pass that searches for `llvm.memcpy` intrinsics and inserting a post-call to the instrumentation runtime
- The instrumentation runtime contains a `std::map` structure
- The underlying libc++ code that implements `std::map` has been instrumented, and in turn calls the instrumentation runtime again

When I run the program, it freezes once the first instrumentation call is made. The suspected loop is `trace_memcpy` > `std::map::operator[]` > `trace_memcpy` > and so forth

Is there a way to short-circuit this loop, e.g. can the instrumentation library inspect the call stack to see that it is already *in* the call the stack and return early from the `trace_memcpy` function?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick & dirty & probably not bulletproof - add a `static` variable to the implementation of `trace_memcpy` to avoid nesting.

```
void trace_memcpy(void)
{
    static int nested;
    if (nested)
    {
        return;
    }

    nested = 1;

    // whatever your actual trace logic is

    nested = 0;
}
```

If you need something more sophisticated, use the appropriate concurrency object as provided by your system.